# Error upgrading PHP 5.3 to 5.4 on CentOS 5.10

Tags: php, centos, upgrade

I'm following the KB Parallels upgrade instructions to upgrade PHP 5.3 to 5.4 on a CentOS5.10 machine

http://kb.parallels.com/en/115833 .

Step one advises to open the Autoupdater and check that PHP5 is selected. In my case, PHP5.3 is selected. I un-check PHP5.3 and check PHP5 then update changes. At this point, Plesk errors with the following:

```
Can't find solution for 'obsolete_mode_solution for php53-cli' of dummy_masterpackage_for_dependency-1.2.3.
```

I searched around and found a forum thread where the following two commands are recommended:

```
rpm -e php53-cli-5.3.3-5.el5 --nodeps
rpm -e php53-5.3.3-5.el5 --nodeps
```

These packages are not found and the above command returns the following error:

```
error: package php53-cli-5.3.3-5.el5 is not installed
error: package php53-5.3.3-5.el5 is not installed
```

All advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution found on the lower section of the following page

http://kb.parallels.com/en/115833